# Batch For /L (0, 1, 100) Loop only even numbers?

Tags: loops, batch-file

I want to transfer all even numbers between 1 and 100 in a .csv file. I tried this:

```
SET CSV_Name=
SET /P CSV_Name=Please enter the CSV Name.

ECHO Number;Square;Cubic >> C:\Users\A78100264\Desktop\%CSV_Name%.csv

FOR /L  %%A IN (0, 1, 100) DO (
 SET /A d=%%A / 2
 SET /A e=%d% * 2
 IF %%A == %e% (
 ECHO %%A
 ECHO %%A >> C:\Users\A78100264\Desktop\%CSV_Name%.csv
 )
 )
```

But that doesn't work. Does someone have a better idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Any error? Getting odd numbers as well? Can you explain?

Comment: Search for _delayed expansion_.  As you have it, the values of `%d%` and `%d%` are expanded _once_ when the `for` loop starts, and not (as one might expect) re-evaluated each time around the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your own answer actually outputs all even numbers between 0 and 100 inclusive:

```bat
FOR /L %%A IN (0 2 100) DO …
```

Technically this would achieve your question's goal, *(all even numbers between 1 and 100)*:

```bat
FOR /L %%A IN (2 2 98) DO …
```

Answer (score 0):

I just realised I can just do:

```
FOR /L  %%A IN (0, 2, 100) DO (
 ECHO %%A
 ECHO %%A >> C:\Users\A78100264\Desktop\%CSV_Name%.csv
 )
```

Comment: Yes. It helps when you read the help file. `(start,step,end)`